# Characteristics of the Navier-Stokes equations as a set of PDE's

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, mathematics, differential-equations, navier-stokes

I am not entirely sure if I should ask this question here or not, but here goes: can anyone suggest any reference (book, article, etc.) about the Navier-Stokes equations from a mathematical point view? In other words, works that go into detail about the properties of the NS equations as a set of PDE's and the properties of the solutions (if any)(including attempts to prove that the solution is smooth and its energy is bounded over time). I am also interested in alternative models like Leray's, Holm's and Ladyzenskaja's models.

I don't know where to start my search, so any nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Schlichting's book "Boundary-Layer Theory" is more of an advanced engineering text, but it does have a chapter on the NS equations & another on exact solutions.

Comment: @D.Halsey Thank you for you suggestion. I am well aware of Schlichting's book, to which i often turn for reference, but I am not looking for specific solutions to simple configurations. I am looking for texts that tackle the NS equations as a mathematical problem.

Comment: This is only an article to get a general gimps into a new approach of how energy might be bounded. https://www.quantamagazine.org/terence-tao-proposes-fluid-new-path-in-navier-stokes-problem-20140224/ Leray's, Holm's models will be waste of time to digest information from. They don't get brought up often, but Ladyzenskaja's model would be a good start. Properties of the NSE can be seen here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/09/03/254a-notes-0-physical-derivation-of-the-incompressible-euler-and-navier-stokes-equations/ Good luck :)